# Looking for a method to organize GPS data from days to sessions (cases of continious data stretching into the next day)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have thousands of recorded GPS points stored by date and time, broken apart into their source videos, each of which was created each minute.

Sessions are when the GPS recorder started and until it ended, which in a few cases went from 9pm to 4am the next day.   They're broken apart in time by atleast 6 hours but typically more like 12 hours.

Unfortunately when I was collecting the raw data there was no way to know if I was breaking up one session to the next and atleast a dozen times a block of recording that started on one date and stretch to the next was broken apart.   Now I am trying to figure out how to reorganize them back.

All of the data is stored in a sqlite database with a schema like:

```
session
    date
    videos # relationship(Video)

Video:
    datetime # includes the minute of the day it was recorded
    coordinates # relationship(Coordinates)

Coordinate:
    latitude = string # (not float to avoid loss of precision)
    longitude = string 
    datetime = # includes the date, minute, and second
```

I tried a brute force approach like this

```
def find_gaps():
   """
       Assume the bulk of a session's videos are in the correct
       location but the head or tail may not be

       12567
       12,567
       89012567
       89012, 567

   """

   for session in db.Session.query.order_by(db.Session.date.asc()):
       videos = list(session.videos)
       blocks = list()
       block = [videos.pop(0)]
       for video in videos:
           delta = video.datetime - block[-1].datetime
           minutes = delta.seconds / 60
           print(delta.days, minutes)
           if minutes > 15:
               print(video.name, minutes)
               blocks.append(block)
               block = [video]
           else:
               block.append(video)

       if block:
           blocks.append(block)

   if len(blocks) > 1:
       print(len(blocks))
```

but never implemented sorting logic as I realized this would still keep sessions that overlap two dates apart.

Another idea I had was to walk through all of the Video records (datetime - hour and minute) in sets of overlapping three days (prior day, current day, next day) but I couldn't think of a way of finding the actual sessions.

## Irrelevant

I've recorded both my times driving for Lyft as well as my road trips from Denver to Anchorage, Alaska and back (I like to drive).   The road trip data is more important to me but it is also the most complicated, especially last years data set.  I shattered my sun roof from a stray rock and then shredded a tire so I ended up limping ~3200 miles with a spare time and a duct taped roof in 12 hour runs with 6 hour rest stop at 70 Kph (~45mph).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of SQLite, it will have support for [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html).  If you don't have a recent version, you can upgrade fairly easily.  I strongly recommend using that.

Window functions provide a way in SQL to effectively do the operation of putting a data set in order, and then comparing neighbors, doing running tabs, and so on.  The syntax is a bit cumbersome, and solving them tends to naturally lead to nested queries.  It takes a little getting used to.

For a start, let's write a query that gives us `Video` with the datetime of the previous video (warning, all queries are untested and could be broken)

```
SELECT datetime
  , coordinates
  , lag(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY strftime('%s',datetime)) as last_datetime
FROM Video
```

(Note that the default frame is unbounded preceding to the current row, which means that we have access to previous videos but not future ones.  I will use that fact again, but won't note it.)

Now let's make a query that is the same, except that we know which entries start a session which I'll define as there wasn't any entry for the previous hour.

```
SELECT datetime
  , coordinates
  , CASE
       WHEN strftime('%s',datetime) - strftime('%s',last_datetime) < 3600
       THEN 0
       ELSE 1
    END as is_session_start
FROM (
    SELECT datetime
      , coordinates
      , lag(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY strftime('%s',datetime)) as last_datetime
    FROM Video
  ) AS video_and_prev_datetime
```

And now we'll tag each video with the datetime of the start of its session.

```
SELECT datetime
  , coordinates
  , MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN is_session_start = 1
        THEN strftime('%s',datetime)
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) OVER (
      ORDER BY strftime('%s',datetime)
    ) AS session_start
FROM (
    SELECT datetime
      , coordinates
      , CASE
           WHEN strftime('%s',datetime) - strftime('%s',last_datetime) < 3600
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
        END as is_session_start
    FROM (
        SELECT datetime
          , coordinates
          , lag(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY strftime('%s',datetime)) as last_datetime
        FROM Video
      ) AS video_and_prev_datetime
  ) as video_and_session_start
```

And now you have your videos categorized by session start time.

---

If you prefer to do this in code, I recommend just sorting `Video` by `strftime('%s',datetime)` and then doing the same kind of "compare to the last, keep track of session starts and add them" in code.  But given that window functions are coming to more and more databases over time, you might as well get to know how to use them as I just demonstrated.